# Role of isotropy argument in fixing the form of $T^\mu_\nu$ of cosmology (Padmanabhan's book)

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, universe, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The following lines from [Gravitation Foundation and Frontiers by T. Padmanabhan](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BSfe2MjbQ3gC&pg=PA466&lpg=PA466&dq=padmanabhan%20it%20is%20conventional%20to%20write%20such%20an%20energy-momentum%20tensor&source=bl&ots=8zkFTwknmp&sig=ACfU3U26lw4nnnNs9R-k5-BQQG6YA_Km7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz35axtr3mAhV8zjgGHWS5DQMQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=padmanabhan%20it%20is%20conventional%20to%20write%20such%20an%20energy-momentum%20tensor&f=false) (he uses Latin indices for spacetime and Greek indices for space, which is unusual)

> The assumption of isotropy implies that $T^\mu_0$ must be zero.

1. Why should the assumption of isotropy imply $T^\mu_0=0$? I think assumption of isotropy only implies $T^1_0=T^2_0=T^3_0$.

> The assumption of isotropy implies that $T^\mu_0$ must be zero and the spatial components $T^\alpha_\beta$ must have diagonal form with $T^1_1=T^2_2=T^3_3$.

2. Why? I think isotropy only implies $T^1_2=T^2_1=T^2_3=T^3_2=T^1_3=T^3_1$ and $T^1_1=T^2_2=T^3_3$. Why off diagonal elements be zero from isotropy?

Please explain what isotropy can say and what it cannot.

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161965/

Comment: *he uses greek indices for spacetime and latin indices for space, which is unusual* This is not unusual; in fact it is extremely common. I consider it the standard convention for indices. You may have said it backwards from what you meant. It’s hard to tell from the short quote what convention the book is using, but he may be using Greek indices for space, which is uncommon.

Comment: @G.Smith Fixed. thanks